# AudioUnitRender returns null into AudioBufferList on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, avfoundation, core-audio

I'm create audio file from AVAudioEngineOutput by AudioUnitRender. On iPhone this realization works fine, but on iPad I got void audio file with right duration. Why this can happen?

**Main method**

```
NSTimeInterval duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration);

NSUInteger lengthInFrames = (NSUInteger) (duration * audioDescription->mSampleRate);

    const NSUInteger kBufferLength = 1024; //3756;

    AudioBufferList *bufferList = AEAllocateAndInitAudioBufferList(*audioDescription, kBufferLength);
    AudioTimeStamp timeStamp;
    memset (&timeStamp, 0, sizeof(timeStamp));
    timeStamp.mFlags = kAudioTimeStampSampleTimeValid;
    OSStatus status = noErr;
    for (NSUInteger i = kBufferLength; i < lengthInFrames; i += kBufferLength) {
        status = [self renderToBufferList:bufferList writeToFile:audioFile bufferLength:kBufferLength timeStamp:&timeStamp];
        if (status != noErr)
            break;
    }
    if (status == noErr && timeStamp.mSampleTime < lengthInFrames) {
        NSUInteger restBufferLength = (NSUInteger) (lengthInFrames - timeStamp.mSampleTime);
        AudioBufferList *restBufferList = AEAllocateAndInitAudioBufferList(*audioDescription, (Float32)restBufferLength);
        status = [self renderToBufferList:restBufferList writeToFile:audioFile bufferLength:restBufferLength timeStamp:&timeStamp];
        AEFreeAudioBufferList(restBufferList);
    }


    SInt64 fileLengthInFrames;
    UInt32 size = sizeof(SInt64);
    ExtAudioFileGetProperty(audioFile, kExtAudioFileProperty_FileLengthFrames, &size, &fileLengthInFrames);
    AEFreeAudioBufferList(bufferList);
    ExtAudioFileDispose(audioFile);
    if (status != noErr)
        [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"See logs for details"];
    else {
        NSLog(@"Finished writing to file at path: %@ \n File size must be %f Mb", path,(tmpData.length/1024.0)/1024.0);
        [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Success!" message:@"Now you can play a result file"];
    }
```

**Allocating of buffer**

```
AudioBufferList *AEAllocateAndInitAudioBufferList(AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat, int frameCount) {
    int numberOfBuffers = audioFormat.mFormatFlags & kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved ? audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame : 1;
    int channelsPerBuffer = audioFormat.mFormatFlags & kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved ? 1 : audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
    int bytesPerBuffer = audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame * frameCount;
    AudioBufferList *audio = malloc(sizeof(AudioBufferList) + (numberOfBuffers - 1) * sizeof(AudioBuffer));
    if (!audio) {
        return NULL;
    }
    audio->mNumberBuffers = numberOfBuffers;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBuffers; i++) {
        if (bytesPerBuffer > 0) {
            audio->mBuffers[i].mData = calloc(bytesPerBuffer, 1);
            if (!audio->mBuffers[i].mData) {
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) free(audio->mBuffers[j].mData);
                free(audio);
                return NULL;
            }
        } else {
            audio->mBuffers[i].mData = NULL;
        }
        audio->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize = bytesPerBuffer;
        audio->mBuffers[i].mNumberChannels = channelsPerBuffer;
    }
    return audio;
}
```

**Rendering method**

```
- (OSStatus)renderToBufferList:(AudioBufferList *)bufferList
                   writeToFile:(ExtAudioFileRef)audioFile
                  bufferLength:(NSUInteger)bufferLength
                     timeStamp:(AudioTimeStamp *)timeStamp {
    [self clearBufferList:bufferList];
    AudioUnit outputUnit = self.engine.outputNode.audioUnit;
    OSStatus status =AudioUnitRender(outputUnit, 0, timeStamp, 0, (UInt32)bufferLength, bufferList);

    [tmpData appendBytes:bufferList->mBuffers[0].mData length:bufferLength];

    float *data1 = bufferList->mBuffers[0].mData;
    float *data2 = bufferList->mBuffers[1].mData;;

    for(int i=0; i<bufferLength/4; i++)
    {
//On iPad data[i]==0 and data2[i] == 0 
        if(data1[i]!=0||data2[i]!=0)
        NSLog(@"%f - %f",data1[i],data2[i]);
    }

    if (status != noErr) {
        NSLog(@"Can not render audio unit");
        return status;
    }
    timeStamp->mSampleTime += bufferLength;
    status = ExtAudioFileWrite(audioFile, (UInt32)bufferLength, bufferList);
    if (status != noErr)
        NSLog(@"Can not write audio to file");
    return status;
}
```

***Problem occurs in the Rendering method***

Comment: Is `audioFile` null when your write it to `bufferList`?

Comment: I'm write outputUnit  to bufferList, then bufferList  write to audioFile. Signal from outputUnit not null - I can hear it if listetnig it by stream, But in buffer list data is null.

Comment: Oh, this NSData object used just for tests. 
I'm not sure that it will display correctly the current situation . But at this point:

<br/>`for(int i=0; i<bufferLength/4; i++)
    {
//On iPad data[i]==0 and data2[i] == 0 
        if(data1[i]!=0||data2[i]!=0)
        NSLog(@"%f - %f",data1[i],data2[i]);
    }`

 the problem clearly visible .

Comment: If it helps, I took the code from this github thread. https://github.com/VladimirKravchenko/AVAudioEngineOfflineRender

Comment: Try `(Float32 *)data1 = (Float32 *)bufferList->mBuffers[0].mData`. It might be null because it is being casted incorrectly? Just a guess right now

Comment: I do not think the problem is the incorrect type cast . On the iPhone , this code works fine .